# Swift 3 | Adding constraints programmatically doesn't center my subview

Tags: uiimageview, swift3, constraints, center

I try to write an UIImageView extension which display an ActivityIndicator in the middle of my ImageView, I tried the following, note that my ImageViews have a constraint on height (100) and width (100) :

```
public extension UIImageView {
    public func downloadedFrom(url: URL) {

        let activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.gray)
    activityIndicator.startAnimating()

        let leftSpaceConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: activityIndicator, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.left, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.left, multiplier: 1, constant: 40)

        let topSpaceConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: activityIndicator, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top, multiplier: 1, constant: 40)

        let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: activityIndicator, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 20)

        let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: activityIndicator, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 20)

        self.addSubview(activityIndicator)

        self.addConstraints([leftSpaceConstraint, topSpaceConstraint, widthConstraint, heightConstraint])
    }
}
```

I also tried to set leadingSpaceConstraint / trailingSpaceConstraint / horizontalConstraint / verticalConstraint but my code has no effect, every constraints I set doesn't do change anything. My activityIndicator stay at the top left like this :

[image]

I don't understand why ? The method "downloadedFrom" is called in the viewDidLoad like this :

```
myImageView.downloadedFrom(url: imageUrl)
```

Where did I go wrong ? TY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are placing your imageView on the top of parent UIView from the left side. It needs to be depending on coordinates of the middle of parent UIImageView for x-axis and y-axis. And also, set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to false. Look at the code below:

```
     public extension UIImageView {
            public func downloadedFrom(url: URL) {

            let activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.gray)
            activityIndicator.startAnimating()
            activityIndicator.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

            let leftSpaceConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: activityIndicator, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

            let topSpaceConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: activityIndicator, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerY, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

            let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: activityIndicator, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 20)

            let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: activityIndicator, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 20)

            self.addSubview(activityIndicator)

            self.addConstraints([leftSpaceConstraint, topSpaceConstraint, widthConstraint, heightConstraint])
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, you are right, I should use NSLayoutAttribute.centerX and NSLayoutAttribute.centerY but this is not changing anything, my loader is still on top left I can't find a way to center it !

Comment: @Aximem activityIndicator.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false ?

Comment: YES ! Thanks @dasha, you can create a new answer with this and I will accept ;)

Comment: I used to be using SnapKit, where you just have to do : `activityIndicator.snp.makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
            make.width.height.equalTo(20)
            make.center.equalTo(self)
        }` It manages translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints automatically